# How to retrieve a date for a given weekday in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to find a date by providing a weekday. For instance, I want to find the date of last Sunday and this Sunday. How to do it in iOS?

In OSX, NSDate provides a method of dateWithNaturalLanguageString, but iOS does not provide a similar method. Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can calculate using NSDateComponents..

Answer (score -1):

This is Sample. It helps you.

```
NSDate *date     = [NSDate date];           
NSString *dateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:date 
                                                              dateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle 
                                                              timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
NSString *timeString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:date
                                                              dateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle
                                                              timeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

int weekday = [[currentCalendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date] weekday];

NSString *weekdayString = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] shortWeekdaySymbols] objectAtIndex:weekday-1];
```